# not able to save data into excel file

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, excelpackage

```
using (ExcelPackage package = 
new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("jsonToExcel.xlsx")))            
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("abc");   
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonFileName))
    {

        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

        dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        int pos = 1;
        foreach (var item in array["columns"])
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, pos].Value = item["title"];
            pos+=1;
        }
        int Row = 2;

        foreach(var item in array["dataTable"]["itemList"])
        {
            pos = 1;
            worksheet.Cells[Row, pos++].Value = item["itemName"];
            worksheet.Cells[Row, pos++].Value = item["Total"];
            worksheet.Cells[Row, pos++].Value = item["91-150 days"];
            worksheet.Cells[Row, pos++].Value = item["211+ days"];
            worksheet.Cells[Row, pos++].Value = item["151-210 days"];
            worksheet.Cells[Row, pos++].Value = item["0-30 days"];
            Row += 1;
        }
    }
    package.Save();
}
```

Nothing is getting stored in excel file "jsonToExcel". I am using ExcelPackage for storing the contents in the excel file and there is no problem with the json file

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: there is no error message, but when i open the excel file there is nothing in it

Comment: You won't find anything if there was no data to begin with. Did you debug the code? Does the loop run?

Comment: Which library are you using? EPPlus for example allows you to load a sheet using `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection()`

Comment: i have data in json file and the loops are running perfectly and i am using EPPLUS@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: so, just to be 100% clear, can you confirm that you stopped the debugger at the end of the last loop iteration and confirmed that `worksheet.Cells` is populated correctly with all the expected data?

Comment: @MohanKurali EPPlus works. You'll have to provide a sample input string so people can try and reproduce what you describe. The loop is definitely *not* running perfectly, otherwise you'd get a result.

Comment: @MohanKurali perhaps you are checking in the *wrong* location? You used a relative path for the Excel file. During debugging the current directory is `bin/Debug`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i got the reason, i was supposed to use item["itemName"].Value . But i want to know why should i use .Value ?

Comment: @ADyson i am supposed to use .Value but i dont know why?

Comment: @MohanKurali probably because those items are JToken or JObject instances. By using `dynamic` you can't see what the types you use really are. You could have deserialized the data to a specific type and used its properties to avoid this problem.

Comment: @MohanKurali another possibility is that you are setting a cell's Value object, not its text. That Value can be anything - text, DateTime, number. JToken has a *lot* of implicit conversion operators. If you assigned it to a `string` property you'd get its string representation. By assigning it to an `object` though you get the JToken itself. Consider using *explicit* casts to ensure you store the type you want into the cells, eg `(int)item["Total"];` or `(decimal)item["Total"];`

Comment: explicit cast is giving the same problem @PanagiotisKanavos